# How to learn MVC 3 and Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have a need to learn MVC 3 with the Razor view engine and Entity Framework 4, and am trying to figure out where to start.

Over a year ago, I build a site in MVC 2 and LINQ to SQL, but it's been a long time since I've thought about it at all and I've forgotten a lot. Though, I still have a loose understanding of routing, action links, and a bit of LINQ. So, I'm not exactly starting from scratch, but it feels like it.

I've been doing lots of digging around, in order to learn what I can, but have really only begun to feel a bit overwhelmed. I watched the videos on http://www.asp.net/mvc. While these certainly helped, there are still lots of holes in my knowledge.

In any case, here are some specific things I'm hoping you guys can help me find:

- a good, hands-on MVC 3 tutorial (not unlike the nerd dinner tutorials that were available for MVC 2)
- a clear explanation of Entity Framework 4, including coverage of
  topics such as lazy loading and POCO objects
- a clear explaination of LINQ, focusing on all of the extension
  methods available, etc
- resources that are NOT focused on code first models. I already have a
  database that is in use (I'm not sure I see the value in code
  first anyway)

Does anyone know of a resource or two that has these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a very handy project which is already build, but who you can build by yourself with tutorials which will guide you through alot of MVC stuff.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples/mvc-music-store

Also I learned alot from the blogs from Stephen Walter: http://stephenwalther.com

Comment: ChristiaanV, thank you for the links!. I will certainly work through those, in order to learn as much as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding EF, I recommend [this book first](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260)

for EF4.1, [this series of post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx) by ADO.NET Team will help you

You still can use EF4.1 with Database First, refer [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx) and [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx) even though you already have database schema

Comment: kwon, thank you for the quality links. I went ahead and purchased that book, and I look forward to reading it. As far as the EF 4.1 stuff is concerned, I installed it, but I'm not sure I'll need it. As I mentioned in my original post, I'm not really interested in Code First. Also, as cool as POCOs sound, they kind of intimidate me because of their inability to "track" themselves, as DataSets or Self-tracking entities do. So, at this point, I am really questioning the the out-of-the-box value of POCOs.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont mind spending a few bucks for a subscription based site (i think they do have a 10 day trial or 90 day if you qualify for dreamspark) the company i work for uses pluralsight for alot of our .net training they have a good chunk of mvc 3 videos that can help you out with getting going and have some more in depth stuff as well

i will up date this post tomorrow when i get to work with the page of information i gave to our mvc developers at work which has a ton of hour + videos and some great articles

also check out the following blogs for extra information 
[haacked.com](http://www.haacked.com) 
[goodscottbadscott.com](http://goodscottbadscott.com)
[scottgu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/)

***Edit:***

[MIX 09 Demos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX09?sort=sequential&direction=desc&term=&s=Phil%2bHaack&s=Scott%2bHanselman)

[PDC 09 Demos](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/PDC/PDC09?sort=sequential&direction=desc&term=&s=Scott%2bHanselman)

[Phil Haack's Intro to Razor View Engine](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Web-Camps-TV-1-ASPNET-MVC-3-Preview-1-and-Razor-Tips-with-Phil-Haack)

[MIX 11 Demos](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX11?q=scott%20hanselman)

[MIX 11 ASP.net MVC 3 The time is now (recommended)](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX11?q=scott%20hanselman)

[HTML5 Resources](http://diveintohtml5.info/)

[Jquery](http://jquery.com/)

[Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com)

[Crystal Reports](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/163050/how-to-use-crystal-report-view-in-asp-net-mvc3.aspx#answer1)

Comment: PluralSite is great. I'm actually trying to get my employer to purchase a subscription as well. Though, in the mean time, perhaps I'll try out the trial period. I'm looking forward to seeing your update, once you are able to get back to this after work.

Comment: No worries I learned mvc form these Scott hanselman does a Great job with his developer talks

Comment: I watched the recommended presentation, "MIX 11 ASP.net MVC 3 The time is now." Phil is obviously a very smart guy, but this particular presentation was ... challenged ;) It had lots of "oops" moments, but it's certainly not like I could do any better. Apart from that though, it was also a bit over my head in many parts.

Comment: oops i forgot to take the recommended part off it was meant for our dev team watch the ones by scott hanselman his talks are generally better and he has a good sense of humor in them the miscrosoft webstack of love is a good one but might still be a bit high level i would try watching the older one from 2009 first it is very badsic starting altough some of it is deprecated now but it is a good place to get started with the concepts ive watched each of these while following along about 5-10 times to get all of the points

Answer (score 0):

I believe watching the PluralSight videos which are free and you can see them in [www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) (left corner ) is the essential step you can do.